# Why json_decode not working?

Tags: php, json

I try to parse json string on server side:

```
$productInJSON = iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $_POST['productInJSON']);
$data = json_decode($productInJSON,true);
echo "<PRE>";
var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
<PRE>NULL
```

$productInJSON:

```
{\"id\":\"17\",\"img\":\"CK0092\",\"title\":\"Серебряное кольцо с гранатом\",\"product\":\"СК0092\",\"size\":\"15,5\",\"size1\":\"\",\"size2\":\"\",\"size3\":\"\",\"size4\":\"\",\"dopInfo\":\"Поверхность изделия обработана нанесением тонкого слоя родия (толщиной 0,1—25 мкм) для повышения отражательной способности, коррозионной стойкости, жаростойкости, обеспечения защитно-декоративных свойств. Под заказ все размеры. Под заказ простое серебрение (нанесение тонкого слоя серебра 999° на поверхность изделия) для обеспечение естественного серебряного цвета.\",\"cost\":\"337\",\"cost1\":\"0\",\"cost2\":\"0\",\"cost3\":\"0\",\"cost4\":\"0\",\"discountSite\":\"15\",\"discountShop\":\"10\",\"metal\":\"Серебро\",\"weight\":\"1,80\",\"weight1\":\"\",\"weight2\":\"\",\"weight3\":\"\",\"weight4\":\"\",\"stone1name\":\"Гранат\",\"stone1ID\":\"14\",\"stone1Number\":\"1\",\"stone1Color\":\"Красный\",\"stone1Purity\":\"\",\"stone1Weight\":\"0,55\",\"stone1Shape\":\"Клуглая\",\"stone2name\":\"\",\"stone2ID\":\"0\",\"stone2Number\":\"\",\"stone2Color\":\"\",\"stone2Purity\":\"\",\"stone2Weight\":\"\",\"stone2Shape\":\"\",\"stone3name\":\"\",\"stone3ID\":\"0\",\"stone3Number\":\"\",\"stone3Color\":\"\",\"stone3Purity\":\"\",\"stone3Weight\":\"\",\"stone3Shape\":\"\",\"stone4name\":\"\",\"stone4ID\":\"0\",\"stone4Number\":\"\",\"stone4Color\":\"\",\"stone4Purity\":\"\",\"stone4Weight\":\"\",\"stone4Shape\":\"\",\"stone5name\":\"\",\"stone5ID\":\"0\",\"stone5Number\":\"\",\"stone5Color\":\"\",\"stone5Purity\":\"\",\"stone5Weight\":\"\",\"stone5Shape\":\"\",\"set1ID\":\"18\",\"set2ID\":\"0\",\"set3ID\":\"0\",\"note1ID\":\"0\",\"cat\":\"1\",\"theme\":\"0\",\"order\":\"0\",\"mail\":\"mouse_2.4.7@mail.ru\",\"giftImg\":\"\",\"giftText\":\"\"}
```

Comment: Basic debugging first. Does the first step result in something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON string fails validation at [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com) with the message

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    \"id\": \"17\",    
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

If it's not JSON then `json_decode()` will return a null

If you use `stripslashes()` on it first you can then decode it.

What version of PHP are you using? Is it possible you have magic quotes turned on?

Comment: It fails, if you use php single quote output. If use double quote it becames normal. Though, I suggest to use `stripslashes()` to fix that.

Comment: I try user stripslashes(). jsonlint.com shows "Valid JSON", but still NULL on json_decode function

Comment: I use: $data = json_decode(str_replace ('\"','"', $_POST['productInJSON']), true); it work :) stripslashes() do the same but I don't know why this stripslashes() result is NULL

Comment: $newJSON = stripslashes($_POST['productInJSON']);
$objProduct = json_decode($newJSON);
exit($objProduct->{'title'});

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slashes before every " and add ' to the start and end of string. It should look something like that

```
$productInJSON='{"id":"17","img":"CK0092","title":"Серебряное кольцо с гранатом"}';
```

To be able to solve your problem